# Visual Studio Fresh Install - Graphics Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is a bit of an obscure question, and possibly not entirely related to Visual Studio but here goes;

I've just migrated my PC from HDD to SSD, with fresh installs of Windows, Visual Studio etc...

I went into the Visual Studio WinForms designer to test some code I was working on, and it seems to have all sorts of issues

1. ListBox constantly flickers in the designer
2. When a ListBox stops flickering (and focused), I cannot see the design time sizing grips
3. Big red cross in the component gutter

[image]

Really obscure, and I'm not even sure this question belongs here..but I can't think of any other options. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have? Have yo checked to make sure you have, or have the correct version of your graphics driver installed on your new Windows install? It could be running off of a built in Windows driver or something. Do other applications have any issues?

Comment: @Cyral nvidia GTX 460, and it's using nvidia experience to install drivers, so it should be picking the correct ones automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UNINSTALLED KASPERSKY INTERNET SECURITY 2015 - SOLVED :-(**

This has not been at all productive!